# How to show/hide markers when zoom level changes?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have some number of markers on my map. I want one group of markers to be visible when zoom level is 1-2, and another set of markers be visible when zoom level is 3 and more.

Is it posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the zoom level and then just hide/show based on the zoom level.

So when the user zooms there is a zoomend event. You can subscribe to it and update your zoomLevel variable accordingly.

```
map.leafletElement.on("zoomend", function (e) {
  this.zoomChange(e.target._zoom);
});
```